# md-hint is not working in angular material

Tags: angular-material

The tag `<md-hint>` is not working in Angular Material 1.1.0-rc2.

I even tried using `<div class="hint"></div>` as defined in Documentation but gives out same result

[image: The output of <md-hint> as well as <div class="hint">]

[image: The code used for it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/XKzrqo) with V1.1.0-rc2 that shows input hints as displayed in the online demos.

`md-hint` is not a directive in Angular Material 1.1.0-rc2

The style of the hints isn't a part of Angular Material but a stand alone CSS (not sure why they don't actually create a `md-hint` directive):

[image]